# how to create API in Spring boot of student details

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to create the following api in spring boot and hit on the postman with Json.
I have created a controller, repository and student class written the code in list format.

```
Create a api while enters student data
/newStudent
Reqeust Body:
{
"name":"Shubham",
"rollno":22,
"studentid":1
}

Response: 

{
"status":"OK",
"message":"Data Added"
}


Create a api while enters studen marks
/enterMarks

Request Body:

{
"studenid":1,
"hindimarks":34,
"mathsmarks":12,
"scimarks":34,
"total":
"avg":
"status":
}

Response: 
{
"status":"OK",
"message":"Data Added"
}


Create a api get get student list
/getStudentList

Response:
[
 {
  "name":"Shubham",
  "rollno":22,
  "studentid":1
 },
 {
  "name":"Aman",
  "rollno":22,
  "studentid":2
 }
]
```

Comment: try this https://www.section.io/engineering-education/how-to-create-a-rest-api-using-spring-boot-maven-and-mysql/

Comment: I am using Spring Suite Tool is it okay with it.

Comment: I have to do it without database @Manish Kumar

Comment: Please reference the Springboot docs https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should consider changing the naming convention for your endpoint. You should be using HTTP Verbs (GET, POST, PUT etc.) instead of using endpoints like "/getStudentList" or "/newStudent", use something like

```
  GET /students 
  POST /student
```

Refer [this](https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-boot-rest-example) for an introduction to creating APIs. Or you could look into Spring's own [guide](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/)